# QGIS - creating vector layer which contain boundary of each raster cell

Tags: vector, boundary, qgis

I would like to show a raster layer and beyond it another layer which contain lines (polylines) which is boundary of cells in other raster layer

I think about split each cell into new raster file and than convert it to vector - maybe there is much easier way?
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/qgispyt.png/

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562/1228)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer to myself.

By using *gdalinfo* I can get exactly coordinates of raster corners and number of cells.
If I use this information I can generate a GML file - unfortunately I have problem with it:
[qgis GML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117743/gml-manually-created-problem)

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please, if you solve your problem yourself, mark your answer as accepted. If you just want to add extra info, edit your post or add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, there's a more easy way to do this.
In Quantum GIS:
Vector > Research Tools > Vector Grid

- Copy the spatial attributes of another layer (that is opened)
- Choose a resolution that is not too small (otherwise your layer is just a black patch)
- Choose lines

Default, the resulting layer will have a fill color, even when you selected lines and not polygons. You can change this in the Properties your layer.

- Click Edit (or button with wrench icon)
- Choose 'No fill' for Fill style

You're done!